# Range of greatest integer function.

Tags: functions

Find the range of $f(x)=x-[x]$ ,where $[x]$ stands for greatest integer function.
The answer could be any of these $[0,1]$ or $[0,1)$ or $(0,1)$ or $(0,1]$.
Can someone help with this?

Comment: $[0,1)$ is the correct answer

Comment: Solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that for$ x=k\in \mathbb {Z}$ , we have $x-[x]=0$.

On the other hand if $k<x<k+1$ then $0<x-[x]=x-k<1$

Therefore the range of $x-[x]$ is $[0,1)$